# Use ACF array values in shortcode

Tags: shortcode, advanced-custom-fields

I have a client using some third party forms that I want to easily drop in places on their site.

To easily update them site-wide I thought I would create an ACF repeater field on an options page with fields for `form_id` and `form_markup` that I could use to build the shortcode. The idea being a user could enter just the id of the form in the shortcode and the form would output.

i.e. `[form form_id="1"]`

The question is: how do I call the proper ID from the array of data? Here's where I started:

```
function form_shortcode( $atts ) {

    // Attributes
    shortcode_atts(
        array(
            'form_id'   => '',
        ), $atts
    )

    $forms = get_field( 'forms', 'option' );
    foreach ( $forms as $form ) {
        $form_id = get_sub_field( 'form_id', 'option' );
    }

    return $form_id;

}

add_shortcode( 'form', 'form_shortcode' );
```

I know this isn't correct, but I'm having trouble figuring out exactly how this should even work logistically. Am I even close?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$atts['form_id']` contains the `form_id` that was passed with the Shortcode. You are searching for this `form_id` among the data that is held in the `forms` field.

`$forms` is an array, and each item in the array is another array with your two keys: `form_id` and `form_markup`.

So, for each item in `$forms`, you want to check if that `form_id` matches the `form_id` requested in the Shortcode. if there is a match, `return` the `form_markup` from that item.

If no matches were found, `return` an error message.

```
$forms = get_field( 'forms', 'option' );
foreach ( $forms as $form ) {
    if( $atts['form_id'] == $form['form_id'] ){
        return $form['form_markup'];
    }
}

return 'form id ' . $atts['form_id'] . ' not found';
```